# GSON; How to handle END_DOCUMENT?

Tags: java, gson

I have made a custom type adapter for a tree structure. I declare it as follows:

```
    ModelTypeAdapter adapter = new ModelTypeAdapter();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter( MyObject.class, adapter);
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    MyObject[] results = gson.fromJson(data, MyObject[].class);
```

The type adapter implements the following method:

```
@Override
public MyObject read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    JsonToken token = reader.peek();
    if (token == JsonToken.END_DOCUMENT) {
        return null;
    }
    MyObject result = null;
    try {
        result = readNode(reader);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

The recursive method `readNode` parses the data string perfectly, but once `END_DOCUMENT` is reached, the system gets trapped in an endless loop, because it keeps reparsing the `END_DOCUMENT` token.

1. Closing the reader does not help, because GSON starts to complain
2. Trying to read a next token (e.g. skipValue) doesn't help either

I am using Gson 2.8. Does anyone know to fix this problem?

Comment: Hello, I will not answer by rather suggest for you:

1- Show your readNode method
2- Simplify your code to use while(jsonReader.hasNext() {
  
}

Read a bit more about JsonReader
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson-jsonreader.html

Comment: obviously the caller of `read` doesn't react if it receives null. it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the cause of the problem. I could recreate the problem when I parsed the following String:

```
[{}]
```

As it transpired, Gsonbuilder starts to process the array, and calls my ModelTypeAdapter when BEGIN_OBJECT ('{') is detected . As the ModelTypeAdapter handled the END_ARRAY (']'), the builder got stuck in the END_DOCUMENT token.

Also my readNode had the following construction:

```
while(!JsonToken.END_DOCUMENT.equals(token )) && jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
    token = jsonReader.peek();
    ...
}
```

This should be:

```
while(!completed && jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
    token = jsonReader.peek();
    ...
    completed = endOfMyObject( token );
}
```

Lesson learned: when making a type adapter, concentrate on handling the single object, and not on the array structure it could be part of. And don't check on END_DOCUMENT in the loop, because that will creating probems with nested objects.

That all makes sense, of course.